# How to send e-mail from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, smtp

I have configured database mail – send email ...create one account also... I used below query

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profile_sp
@profile_name = 'SQL 2008 Profile',
@description = 'Used for general-purpose emailing.'
```

The second script creates the new SMTP account:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_account_sp
@account_name = 'MailAcct1',
@description = 'SMTP Account.',
@email_address = 'jojin127@gmail.com',
@display_name = 'Mail Account',
@mailserver_name = 'smtp.gmail.com' ;
```

The third script associates this new account with the new profile:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_profileaccount_sp
@profile_name = 'SQL 2008 Profile',
@account_name = 'MailAcct1',
@sequence_number =1;

exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_add_principalprofile_sp
@profile_name = 'SQL 2008 Profile',
@principal_name = 'public',
@is_default = 0 ;


exec msdb.dbo.sysmail_configure_sp 'AccountRetryDelay', 1200
```

After all I go to sent test mail... after write to address getting error like

> your test email has has been queued for processing.Depending on the network speed and the backlog of the SMTP server.it may take several minutes before the email is delivered to the receipt

please help me out...

One more sent test mail they asking one to address in there actually what I need to written
email or servername

Comment: Why did you tag this with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

You should [use SQL Server's built-in mailer](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/). After the wizard is set up, sending mail is trivial:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='PinalProfile',
@recipients='foo@bar.com',
@subject='Hello world',
@body='Hello alien world, from ours, we come in peace.'
```

Comment: Getting one error...... in description                                                  The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 9 (2013-05-10T12:14:53). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (No such host is known). )

Comment: Yes, bar.com is a made up hostname... Change it to a real one.

Comment: boss I used real one...                                          exec sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = 'gmail',
@recipients='jojin127@gmail.com',
@subject='yoyoyoy',
@body='This is body message'

Comment: Gmail requires SSL and there's a checkbox in the wizard to use it, further it requires basic authentication, there's also a form in the same wizard to do this.

Comment: You need to use port 587 for gmail, according to [this](http://sqlbuzz.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/configuring-sql-server-db-mail-to-send-emails-to-your-gmailyahoo-mail/). If that doesn't work, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up database email through SSMS. There are more options in the GUI than you are using in your stored procedures.

You might need to set port number or some other small option that is in fact required.

Also, when sending through Gmail you need to enable external SMTP before you can start using it.

Comment: Even I created SSMS, I am getting error ? Creation happening successful,after that sending time getting error...